# how to declare an associative array in javascript? Unlike PHP, I find it really difficult to implement

Tags: javascript

How do you access a key named "foo" of the 5th element of an array that is the 2nd element of another array that is the value of a hash key named "baz"?

can you provide the basic examples?

Comment: Associative arrays don't exist in JavaScript. You'll have to use objects instead `{ foo: "bar" }`, only don't expect properties to always have the same "index" in an object.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays!  It has (numeric) arrays, and objects.  You can make an object: `{foo: "bar", baz: "foobar"}`, but they are ***unordered***.

Comment: [`JS Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: It might be helpful if you could demonstrate in pseudocode or PHP the functionality you'd like to see. Your written-out description is a bit difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an object:

```
var obj = {
   foo: {
      bar: "yo"
   }
}
console.log(obj["foo"]["bar"]);

// Or you could do this

var obj = {};
obj["foo"] = {};
obj["foo"]["bar"] = "yo";
console.log(obj["foo"]["bar"]);
```

Note the order of an object is not guaranteed and can change depending on the interpreter / compiler.

An array in JavaScript is just an object with numerical indices (With some specific methods - see comment below). In fact pretty much everything in JavaScript is an object.

Comment: Array's have a bunch of methods (e.g. `indexOf`) and properties (e.g. `length`) that you don't get on plain objects.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you access a key named "foo" of the 5th element of an array
>   that is the 2nd element of another array that is the value of a hash
>   key named "baz"?

```
variableName["baz"][1][4]["foo"];
```

Would get you `"The value here"` from

```
var variableName = { baz: [0, [0, 1, 2, 3, { foo: "The value here" }]] };
```

and here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/tWVwe/) to play with